# Read a csv file and create another csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I have a `.csv` file and when I open it via notepad it looks like:

```
ID501501503502
```

And when I print it in the browser via php, it looks like

```
ID 501 501 503 502
```

My code is:

```
$handle = fopen("MonC1.csv", "r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0);
$fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if (! empty($data)) {
  foreach ($data as $item) {
      echo $item."<br>";
     //fputcsv($fh, array($item));
  }
}
```

So basically the `br` tag inside the for loop doesn't work.This is my first problem.

And the second problem is even if I use `fputcsv(now it is turned off)` it doesn't create a actual `csv` file.

Now my question is how come it has got no space in notepad and when I print in browser it gets space?

I have only one column and nothing else.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What HTML is actually generated by that script?

Comment: Actually it's printing the content of csv file.So if the source file which is a csv file contains ID123 then echo is printing ID 1 2 3 . That's it

Comment: Printing where? @EWit asks about source of html reponse.

Comment: Tried with the chr thing but nothing changed.

Comment: Looks to me like your original file is saved with UNIX line endings, and then you're using `fgetcsv` in Windows, so the whole file is being read as one line. There's probably one `<br>` at the end of the whole output.

Comment: hmm... @Interrobang that makes sense. Let me check

Comment: @Interrobang You are right. It's treating as whole single line.So do I need to use explode space and then write to a csv file as new line(taking Verhaeren suggestion in mind)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, it looks like your original file is saved with UNIX line endings, and then you're using `fgetcsv` in Windows, so the whole file is being read as one line. There's probably one `<br>` at the end of the whole output.

So before processing your file, you'll need to preprocess it to convert the line endings.

On Linux, the utility `unix2dos` does what you want. Or, you can simply replace `\n` with `\r\n` in your file.

The other problem is that `fgetcsv` does not turn an entire file into an array. Instead, it reads a single line from your file handle, and converts that to an array. You'll need to read lines inside a loop:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
  // $data contains one line of the CSV, in array form
  // now you can fputcsv the single line
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Now I am getting the data written to an actual csv file.Still not perfect 100% but as it is not related with this question so probably I might post another question after spending some time on it. Once again thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I think it's not working correctly. I did  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) { echo $data[0]."<br>"; } still outputting as a single line in browser.Not sure what's the mistake I am doing.

Comment: You aren't fixing the line endings. There are two things to fix; you've only added the while loop.

Comment: Not sure mate how can I put '\n' if the array contains one single row.

Comment: Do I need to replace \r with  \n