# fgetcsv with newline issue in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file on windows system which I am getting from a mac and the data looks like

```
ID526526526526
```

So you can see there is no new line no delimiter but still it says csv file.However I have the following code which is

```
$csvFile = 'MonC1.csv';
$allRowsAsArray = array();
if (!$fp=fopen($csvFile,"r")) echo "The file could not be opened.<br/>";  
while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 0 , ',')) !== FALSE ) 
{
    $allRowsAsArray[] = $data;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($allRowsAsArray );
echo '</pre>';
```

Now when I print the data in browser it looks like

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => ID
                526
                526
                526
            )
   );
```

Now I am stuck as I can't create another properly delimited csv file with new line using fputcsv.

Any help is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',')` if you are using lower than PHP 5.1.0

Comment: All I want to have the values separated on new line.It doesn't matter if I have 2d or 1d array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a csv file and create another csv file using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492896/read-a-csv-file-and-create-another-csv-file-using-php)

Comment: `cat myfile.csv | hexdump -C | less`

Answer (score 7):

It's having a problem detecting the line endings. Try turning on `auto_detect_line_endings` before you run `fopen`.

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
$csvFile = 'MonC1.csv';
$allRowsAsArray = array();
if (!$fp=fopen($csvFile,"r")) echo "The file could not be opened.<br/>";  
while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 0 , ',')) !== FALSE ) 
{
    $allRowsAsArray[] = $data;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($allRowsAsArray );
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks but the browser hangs if you have 60k rows with line endings